# What hashing algorithm is HashData in Shlwapi.dll based on?

Tags: windows, algorithm, winapi, hash

Does anyone know what algorithm `HashData` in `Shlwapi.dll` is based on?

I've tried looking at the documentation, but it really doesn't give a clue about the underlying implementation.

I see that `HashData` maps data from `{0,1}*` into a given output size, so it somewhat reminds me of a so-called hash function generator.

I don't need a cryptographic secure hash function, but just a function for implementing some data structures.

Comment: this is some simply, fast and noname hashing. not a strong cryptographic hash. in what question ?

Comment: What do you want from your hash?

Comment: Just a reasonable distribution of hash values. Was looking for CRC32 or something alike.

Comment: There are plenty of CRC32 implementations but is that what you want for a dictionary hash?

Comment: Why does the implementation matter? Have you tried this and determined that it doesn't work for your purposes? Note that Microsoft doesn't guarantee that it will. If you need an implementation that fits specific requirements, you should write one of your own or use another library. These functions are shell helpers, exported principally in the interest of judicially-mandated fairness.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to know, there is an implementation in the Wine source tree in file path.c currently at https://source.winehq.org/source/dlls/kernelbase/path.c#4956.

This is apparently a variant of a hash I found implemented here: https://www.rpi.edu/locker/23/000723/parcel/rlt-portlib/lib/SymT/SymT_hash.c

Comments in that file provide a reference:

> This hash function comes the June 1990 issue of Communications of the
> ACM, volume 33, number 6, pp. 677-680 by Peter K. Pearson.  This uses
> the permutation printed with this article.

Using Window's HashData function provides compatibility with hashes used by some parts of Windows, especially the shell. This is great if you need compatibility or interoperability with Windows. Otherwise it would not be my top choice for a hash function, and would not be considered if I thought I might need to support other platforms.